# How to do word embedding to provide input to RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to do word prediction using  basic RNN. I need to provide input to the RNN cell; I am trying following code

```
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))
Y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))

tfWe = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((V, embedding_dim)))
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(hidden_layer_size, label).astype(np.float32))
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros(label).astype(np.float32))
rnn = GRUCell(num_units = hidden_layer_size, activation = tf.nn.relu)

x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tfWe, X_input)
x = tf.unstack(x, sequence_length, 1)
output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, x, dtype = tf.float32)
output = tf.transpose(output, (1,0,2))
output = tf.reshape(output, (sequence_length*num_samples,hidden_layer_size))
```

I am getting error **ValueError: Layer gru_cell_2 expects 1 inputs, but it received 39 input tensors**. I think this error is due to the embedding as that is not giving a tensor of dimension which can be input to the GRUCell. So, How to provide the input to GRU Cell?

Comment: What's the dimension of tfWe? What's the value of sequence_length?

Comment: sequence length is the maximum length of train data; I am padding the sequence which are less than maximum length of training data;   
tfWe is the embedding weights and corrected the code above accordingly

Comment: Is there any reason for initializing `X_input` as `(None, sequence_length, 1)` and not `(None, sequence_length)`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're initializing `X_input` is probably wrong. That extra one dimension is causing the problem. If you remove that then there's no need to use `unstack`. This following code would work.

```
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length))
Y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length))

tfWe = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((V, embedding_dim)))
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(hidden_layer_size, label).astype(np.float32))
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros(label).astype(np.float32))
rnn = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units = hidden_layer_size, activation = tf.nn.relu)

x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tfWe, X_input)
output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, x, dtype = tf.float32)
##shape of output here is (None,sequence_length,hidden_layer_size)
```

But if you really need to use that dimension then you need to make a small modification in `unstack`. You're unstacking it along `axis=1` into `sequence_length` number of tensors, which again doesn't seem right. So do this:

```
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))
Y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))

tfWe = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((V, embedding_dim)))
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(hidden_layer_size, label).astype(np.float32))
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros(label).astype(np.float32))
rnn = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units = hidden_layer_size, activation = tf.nn.relu)

x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tfWe, X_input)
x = tf.unstack(x, 1, 2)
output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, x[0], dtype = tf.float32)
##shape of output here is again same (None,sequence_length,hidden_layer_size)
```

Lastly if you really really need to unstack it in `sequence_length` number of tensors then replace `unstack` with `tf.map_fn()` and do this:

```
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))
Y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (None, sequence_length, 1))

tfWe = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((V, embedding_dim)))
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(hidden_layer_size, label).astype(np.float32))
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros(label).astype(np.float32))
rnn = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units = hidden_layer_size, activation = tf.nn.relu)

x = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(tfWe, X_input)
x = tf.transpose(x,[1,0,2,3])
##tf.map_fn unstacks a tensor along the first dimension only so we need to make seq_len as first dimension by taking transpose

output,states = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn,x,dtype=tf.float32),x,dtype=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
##shape of output here is (sequence_length,None,1,hidden_layer_size)
```

A warning: Notice the shape of the `output` in each solution. be wary of what type of shape you want.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question about when to use what type of inputs:

Suppose you have 25 sentences, each has 15 words and you divided it into 5 batches of size 5 each. Also, suppose you're using word embedding of 50 dimensions(let's say u are using word2vec), then your input shape would be `(batch_size=5,time_step=15, features=50)`. In this case, you don't need to use unstacking or any kind of mapping.

Next, suppose you have 30 documents, each has 25 sentences, each sentence 15 words long, and you divided documents into 6 batches of size 5 each. Again, suppose you're using word embedding of 50 dimensions, then your input shape has now one extra dimension. Here `batch_size=5`,`time_step=15` and `features=50` but what about number of sentences? Now your input is `(batch_size=5,num_sentences=25,time_step=15, features=50)` which is a invalid shape for any type of `RNNs`. In that case, you need to unstack it along the sentence dimension to make 25 tensors, each will have the shape (5,15,50). To make that work, I used `tf.map_fn`.

Comment: Very helpful explanation! Actually I am new to LSTM and get confused with the shape of the input; I have got it that the shape should be (batch_size, timestep, number_features). So I initiated with the shape (None, sequence_length, 1) - Could you please explain how to decide on input shape
also I found static_rnn and dynamic_rnn and observeed that unstacking is not necessary on dynamic_rnn - Could you please shed some light on it

Comment: It was great !.But still I face some challenges; I am using RNN for entity extraction and I am using a manually annotated file with the label. I am passing it as sequence of words to the GRU cell; I am expecting output should be the label or class but I am getting output as sequence of label

Comment: I have updated the code with lines for output; any suggestion how to get only the  class label as output. Thanks!

Comment: First, make sure output is of shape `(None,sequence_length,hidden_layer_size)`. Generally out at last time step is taken so do `output=output[:,-1,:]`. Now your output has shape `(None,hidden_layer_size)`. Pass this output through a fully connected feed-forward network and give appropriate dimensions to weight matrices and biases in it.

Comment: is output equals to last state for dynamicRNN cell? Can we use last state instead of output?

Comment: States are kind of like intermediate values. They are different from your output. It wouldn't make much sense to use states instead of output.